# Trigger reloadGrid from URL not working

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to trigger reloadGrid event to fetch data from url. However no http request is being made. I have checked through Fiddler.

```
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: 'http://localhost:50570/api/Test/Get/' }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Any thoughts?

Regards,

Abhilash

Comment: is it another url or it is the same when grid first time loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is different url than the first, then add `datatype:"json"`

```
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: 'http:...Your Url' ,datatype:"json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Or if it is same then

```
 $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```